# Angular cli: ng test getting different results if run via "npm run"

Tags: jasmine, angular-cli, karma-jasmine

my package.json contains this script:
`"test:ci": "ng test --no-watch --no-progress --browsers ChromeHeadless"`
If I run *npm run test:ci* all the tests pass, but exits with

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! exotics-client@0.0.0 test:ci: `ng test --no-watch --no-progress --browsers ChromeHeadless`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the exotics-client@0.0.0 test:ci script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

If I instead run 
`ng test --no-watch --no-progress --browsers ChromeHeadless`
without using npm, the tests all pass again, and I don't get the error returning.

Has anyone else seen this issue? Know what's causing it?

Comment: Have you solved this problem ?!

Comment: @ROMAN, I have a vague recollection that it had to do with the --browsers switch... let me check... this is what I have now in Karma.config : 
customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessCI: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-gpu']
      }
    }
and in package.json:
    "test:ci": "ng test --no-watch --no-progress --browsers ChromeHeadlessCI",

Answer (score 6):

In our case the test suite was empty and this was failing the test command without providing any real feedback on why it exited with code 1.

The fix in our case was to add `failOnEmptyTestSuite: false,` in our `karma.config.js`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This answer fixed issue after struggling for 5 hours.